# jQuery, JSON array push

Tags: jquery, json, each

Im having a little problem making this work:

Here is my json array pulled via ajax:

```
{
    "message": [{
        "title": "Account",
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "title": "Content",
        "id": 2
    }, {
        "title": "Other",
        "id": 3
    }]
}
```

here is javascript:

```
var items = [];
$.get("settings.php", {
        getlink: 1,
    }, function(json) {
        $.each(json.message, function() {
            items.push(this);
        });

},"json");

console.log(items)
```

But for some reason items array is always empty []
I can see in firebug, json returned array, but I'm not able to push it.

Comment: The console.log might be happening before the get request is finished, try adding a timeout to test if it worked.

Comment: Add an oncomplete section and put the console.log there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `index, value` that **[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** return :

```
$.each(json.message, function(index, value) {
    items.push(value);
});
```

**NOTE :** `$.each()` is different than **[`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I see my problem now. If I place console.log(items); within ajax get, then I can see the results, but I want to be able to access items array outside of ajax call.

Comment: Yes, you couldn't access the result immediately since `$.get()` is asynchronous, take a look to [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass params to the `$.each` function and push that object to your array.

```js
var json = {
    "message": [{
        "title": "Account",
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "title": "Content",
        "id": 2
    }, {
        "title": "Other",
        "id": 3
    }]
}

var items = [];
$.each(json.message, function(index, item) {
  items.push(item);
});

console.log(items)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```